# How to retrieve a cookie value generated by JavaScript using Python Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm looking to POST on behalf of an account logged in to a website... https://pollev.com

All is well in terms of authenticating the login, retrieving the `csrftoken`, and storing site cookies using Session() in Python requests.

However, upon inspecting the HTTPS traffic the site sends when submitting an answer, it seems the browser is submitting cookies that were never returned upon logging in.  Their names and values are the following:

Seem to be related to the website retrieving analytics.min.js (so maybe these are not important for validating a submission ):

`ajs_anonymous_id = %22390527c4-1481-4b10-9715-5b1f4afe7f79%22`

`cio = 9fa03eb1-235a-04a1-47ef-6b1bc833ca1e`

`ajs_user_id = null`

`ajs_group_id = null`

These are allegedly part of Google Analytics:

`_ga = GA1.2.482358898.1488178639`

`_gat_UA-2204221-8 = 1`

`_gat_UA-2204221-17 = 1`

This one is unknown to me:

`mp_mixpanel__c = 9`

The first cookie doesn't expire for a year according to my browser, and the name leads me to believe the value was somehow generated in the site's javascript.  When I make a POST using Python Requests, I receive Error 422 with content message "Invalid Authenticity Token."

How do I extract these necessary cookie values from the website using Requests, or is it even possible with this module?  I have also tried manually adding each cookie name and value with domain 'pollev.com' to the cookie jar with no luck.

Comment: You cannot know for sure what happens on the backed, if it is not your backend.If this is a result of Javascript, you need either to reverse-engineer the algorythm or to execute the Javascript code in some emulated environment (node.js for example), extract the cookie value and then submit it back. Python alone cannot cope with such tasks.
__ga* - is Google Analytics, btw.

Comment: Thanks, I checked and found that the first four cookie names were listed in analytics.min.js, part of the javascript returned to my browser during a normal answer submission.  Maybe they aren't necessary for authentication if they're all analytics related?   I ask because a similar POST command to retrieve a JSON structure containing a user's previous responses sends those same cookies, bu still works in Requests without sending them.

Comment: GA's cookies are unlikely used by the backend. You could also check, if any additional headers are sent to the sever along with the cookies. The secret may live there.